# How to add release.useAutomaticVersion=true in build.gradle file for auto versioning?

Tags: gradle, gradle-release-plugin

I'm running gradle-release command as follows but I need to movr release.useAutomaticVersion=true inside build.gradle.

./gradlew gitOperations release -Prelease.useAutomaticVersion=true

Comment: Add release.useAutomaticVersion=true to your Gradle.properties

Comment: it is not working, build is failing with below error.
`Could not set unknown property 'useAutomaticVersion' for object of type net.researchgate.release.ReleaseExtension.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
release.useAutomaticVersion=true
```

to my gradle.properties inside the project dir why I apply the release plugin works perfectly. You really added this to the **gradle.properties** and **not** the **build.gradle** ?

Comment: That would be well and good, but release overwrites the gradle.properties file to update the version number, so how did you get this to work?

Comment: gradle release replaces the version and should keep other settings as they are.